# JUnit dependency vs Spring boot starter test dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, spring-test

For the testing part of an REST API. Was looking at the dependencies that you can use in spring boot. I saw that there is the *JUnit dependency* and the *Spring boot starter test dependency*.

What is the difference between the JUnit dependency and the Spring boot starter test dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer:

JUnit, all you need to do for Unit testing.
Think of the asserts (but only [these](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html)) and the JUnit test runner.

Spring Boot Starter Test, think everything you need to run tests where a Spring Context is needed. (Anything where you use @SpringBootTest @Autowired)

What more does the Spring Boot Starter provide?

- Mockito
- Jsonassert

See the full list of compiled dependencies [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.6.7).

Comment: In the list that you put, I saw that spring boot starter test has JUnit-jupiter, does that mean that you don't need to have both dependency separately in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Just remove it and see what happens? :)

Comment: But in all honesty, I am not sure, there are two dependencies to take into account junit-jupiter and jnit-jupiter-engine, I am not sure if the engine (runner) is included in just junit-jupiter.